# Wavelet spectrum in R

Tags: r

I want to draw a wavelet Spectrum on temperature in R.I have plotted the wavelet power spectra and corresponding time series using this code

`out.wave <- morlet(y1 = CAMstd, x1 = Years, p2 = 9, dj = 0.1, siglvl = 0.99)
wavelet.plot(out.wave, useRaster = NA)`

I like to draw global Wavelet Spectrum along with it.
 Can anyone help me out? (wavelet power spectra and global wavelet spectrum in the same row)
[This image is just for reference that I got from internet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IbKLq.png)

Comment: Sorry, but package recommendations are explicitly off-topic here. You'd do better searching google, and then coming back once you have a specific question about implementation.

Comment: sorry.... I have made some changes in the question. :)